# Return Generic Type data from function

Tags: c++, function, generics, return, virtual

I have written the following code. Where the function *func()* print the header and data.

```
class ICell
{
    public:
        wstring header;
        virtual void Fetch() = 0;
};

template <class T>
class Cell : public ICell
{
public:
    //wstring header;
    T data;
    void Fetch()
    {
        wcout<< header << L": ";
        cout<<data<<endl;
    }
  // implementation of cell methods
};

class Row
{
public:
  vector <ICell *> cells;
};
```

Is there any way to return the data instead of print within the function? If so, which portion of the code should be modified? 
Thanks in advance.

```
int main()
{
    Cell<int>c1;
    Cell<double>c2;

    c1.header = L"Roll", c1.data = 100;
    c2.header = L"CGPA", c2.data = 3.5;

    Row r;
    r.cells.push_back(&c1);
    r.cells.push_back(&c2);

    vector <ICell *>::iterator it;
    for(it=r.cells.begin();it!=r.cells.end();it++)
    {
        //checkt type of it wherther it points Cell<int> or Cell<double>
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I have changed my question here. In main() inside the loop how can I check the object type which is pointed by 'it'?

Thank you all for patience and helping me :)

Comment: Change `void Fetch();` to `T Fetch();`

Comment: You could return a string of the data that you are outputting, perhaps?

Comment: @AlokSave: Not if both `T` and `header` are to be returned as one unit...

Comment: @AlokSave the base class has no idea what the datatype will be. What he needs is CRTP but then it doesn't work with virtual functions. There's simply no way out of it.

Comment: I'm suspecting an XY question here...

Comment: I have edited the question. Please check once more.

Comment: Your `ICell` interface doesn't really have much sense in a strongly typed language. The known return type of `Fetch` is a part of the interface, and if the interface doesn't specify it, it isn't going to be useful. You might be coding yourself into a corner, try a redesign.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easiest way is to use `dynamic_cast`:

```
vector <ICell *>::iterator it;
for(it=r.cells.begin();it!=r.cells.end();it++)
{
    Cell<int>* cell_i= dynamic_cast<Cell<int>*>(*it);
    if(cell_i)
    {
       do_something(cell_i->data);
       continue;
    }

    Cell<double>* cell_d= dynamic_cast<Cell<double>*>(*it);
    if(cell_d)
    {
       do_something(cell_d->data);
       continue;
    } 
}
```

Better way is to use visitor pattern:

```
class ICellVisitor; //declaration for ICell to understand ICell* pointer
class ICell
{   public:
    ~ICell(){}; // important
    std::wstring header;
    virtual void visit( ICellVisitor* v ) = 0;
};
template <class T> class Cell; // for Cell<T>* pointer
class ICellVisitor
{   public:
    virtual void visit( Cell<int>* c ) = 0;
    virtual void visit( Cell<double>* c ) = 0;
    virtual void visit( Cell<float>* c ) = 0;
    virtual void visit( Cell<long long>* c ) = 0;
};
template <class T> class Cell : public ICell
{   public:
    //wstring header;
    T data;
    void visit( ICellVisitor* v )
    {
        std::wcout<< header << L": ";
        v->visit(this);
    }
  // implementation of cell methods
};
class Row
{ public:
  std::vector <ICell *> cells;
};
```

Now we need definition of concrete visitor to keep the algorithm for each type:

```
class MyCellVisitor: public ICellVisitor
{   public:
    void visit( Cell<int>* c ){ 
        std::wcout<<"(int)"<<c->data<<std::endl; 
    }
    void visit( Cell<double>* c ){ 
        std::wcout<<"(double)"<<c->data<<std::endl;
    }
    void visit( Cell<float>* c ){ 
        std::wcout<<"(float)"<<c->data<<std::endl;
    }
    void visit( Cell<long long>* c ){ 
        std::wcout<<"(long long)"<<c->data<<std::endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Cell<int>c1;
    Cell<double>c2;
    c1.header = L"Roll", c1.data = 100;
    c2.header = L"CGPA", c2.data = 3.5;
    Row r;
    r.cells.push_back(&c1);
    r.cells.push_back(&c2);
    MyCellVisitor visitor;
    std::vector <ICell *>::iterator it;
    for(it=r.cells.begin();it!=r.cells.end();it++)
    {
        (*it)->visit( &visitor );
    }
    return 0;
}
```